Elasticsearch Datetime Mapping for localized zone-offset in Brackets
I have an index in Elasticsearch that needs to take datetime formats in the following variations:
08/23/2023 8:00:00 PM(UTC+0)
2023-08-23T20:00:00+0000

I can't get an Elasticsearch mapping for the first one with the UTC in brackets, I've tried:
MM/dd/yyyy K:mm:ss a'('O')' which I thought would work according to the docs - https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html
I did get an Elasticsearch mapping that works, but it wouldn't work if there was an offset in the brackets.
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "date": {
        "type":   "date",
        "format": "date_optional_time||MM/dd/yyyy K:mm:ss a'(UTC+0)'"
      }
    }
  }
}

Any help would be massively appreciated

I believe that depending on locale pattern letter O will expect either GMT or UTC and will fail if the input string contains the other one. Does Elastic Search allow you to specify a locale?? In Java DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/d/uuuu h:mm:ss a(O)", Locale.FRENCH) works for parsing your example string.

Your issue isn't very easy, but interesting. Solution is to write a date as text into a specialized field named date_as_text and to update_by_query into the date field
Mapping
PUT /specific_date_format
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "date_as_text": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "date": {
                "type": "date",
                "format": "date_optional_time||MM/dd/uuuu h:mm:ss a'(UTC'x')'"
            }
        }
    }
}

Sample documents with dates of different offsets and formats
PUT /specific_date_format/_bulk
{"create":{"_id":1}}
{"date_as_text":"08/23/2023 8:00:00 PM(UTC+0)"}
{"create":{"_id":2}}
{"date_as_text":"08/23/2023 8:00:00 PM(UTC+2)"}
{"create":{"_id":3}}
{"date_as_text":"08/23/2023 8:00:00 PM(UTC-2)"}
{"create":{"_id":4}}
{"date_as_text":"08/23/2023 8:00:00 PM(UTC+12)"}
{"create":{"_id":5}}
{"date_as_text":"08/23/2023 8:00:00 PM(UTC-12)"}
{"create":{"_id":6}}
{"date_as_text":"2023-08-23T20:00:00+0000"}

Update by query
POST /specific_date_format/_update_by_query
{
    "script": {
        "source": """
            ctx._source.date = /(\(UTC[+-])([0-9]\))/.matcher(ctx._source.date_as_text).replaceFirst('$10$2');
        """
    }
}

Let's search
GET /specific_date_format/_search?filter_path=hits.hits.fields
{
    "fields": [
        "date_as_text",
        "date"
    ],
    "_source": false
}

Response
{
    "hits" : {
        "hits" : [
            {
                "fields" : {
                    "date" : [
                        "2023-08-23T20:00:00.000Z"
                    ],
                    "date_as_text" : [
                        "08/23/2023 8:00:00 PM(UTC+0)"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "fields" : {
                    "date" : [
                        "2023-08-23T18:00:00.000Z"
                    ],
                    "date_as_text" : [
                        "08/23/2023 8:00:00 PM(UTC+2)"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "fields" : {
                    "date" : [
                        "2023-08-23T22:00:00.000Z"
                    ],
                    "date_as_text" : [
                        "08/23/2023 8:00:00 PM(UTC-2)"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "fields" : {
                    "date" : [
                        "2023-08-23T08:00:00.000Z"
                    ],
                    "date_as_text" : [
                        "08/23/2023 8:00:00 PM(UTC+12)"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "fields" : {
                    "date" : [
                        "2023-08-24T08:00:00.000Z"
                    ],
                    "date_as_text" : [
                        "08/23/2023 8:00:00 PM(UTC-12)"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "fields" : {
                    "date" : [
                        "2023-08-23T20:00:00.000Z"
                    ],
                    "date_as_text" : [
                        "2023-08-23T20:00:00+0000"
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}

As you can see, all dates are recognized
